# How to display a popup only once during a for statement? Java

Tags: java

I'm getting a list of appointments from a database in mySQL.  I want to display an alert if there is an appointment within 15 minutes of logging in and if there are no appointments within 15 minutes to display a separate message.  This is what I have so far and I've tried a handful of different ways to phrase the if-else statement but I know the for statement will iterate through each appointment.  How can I only show one pop-up instead of a pop-up for every appointment in the list?

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

    ObservableList<Appointments> appointmentList = DBAppointments.getAllAppointments();

    boolean upcoming = false;
    for(Appointments appt : appointmentList) {
        //boolean upcoming = false;
        if (appt.getAppointmentStart().isAfter(now) && appt.getAppointmentStart().isBefore(now.plusMinutes(15))) {
            upcoming = true;
            Alert alert3 = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert3.setHeaderText("UPCOMING APPOINTMENT");
            alert3.setContentText("Upcoming appointment within 15 minutes: Appointment " + appt.getAppointmentID() + " starting at " + appt.getAppointmentStart());
            alert3.showAndWait();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!  I just added the boolean for "upcoming" and tried working with it but couldn't wrap my head around a solution.

Comment: Set the boolean in the loop, and then after the loop check it and show the alert if it's true.

Comment: @tgdavies I set "boolean upcoming = false;" before the if statement that checks the appointment time being within 15 minutes.  If the appointment is within 15 I have upcoming = true;.  How would I structure the else statement if none of the appointments in the list are within 15 minutes?  I keep getting a pop-up displaying for each individual appointment from the list.

Comment: "Display a popup". Now we are talking about displaying something it probably means there should be another tag here. I'm guessing it's Android

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a break, I used a return statement.  The if statement checks if an appointment is within 15 minutes while iterating through the list.  If there is a match, it displays the alert of an upcoming appointment.  If no appointment matches the if statement condition, the default "no upcoming appointments" alert is popped up.